# Question about RandomAccessFile in Java?

Tags: java

I am reading some Java text about RandomAccessFile, in the text, the author says:

```
RandomAccessFile(File file, String mode)
```

- Mode  **“r”** to open the file for reading only

  Mode **“rw”** to open for both reading and writing

  Mode **“rws”** is same as rw and any changes to  the file’s content or
  metadata take place immediately (since java 5)

  Mode **“rwd”** is same as rw, and changes to the file content, but not
  its metadata, take place immediately (since java 5)

I am not sure that I understand the difference between “rws” and “rwd”. I have tried to run some related code but did not see any points?

Can anyone have a clear example, please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

File metadata in Java is explained [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileAttr.html). An example of metadata that might not be updated immediately with "rwd" mode would be if you set the file modification time by calling `Files.setLastModifiedTime(file, time)`.